# edit: how to design and implement an experiment to do benchmark comparisons of the two queue implementations in python

Tags: python, amortized-analysis, amortization

I am looking for pointers on how to design an experiment to compare the behaviour of `queue` implementations one done with `python list` and the other `python queue abstract data type` using a benchmark.

Here is some code I could put up based on the how I understood `amortized testing`

```
###############################################################
# Experiment to determine the differences between a list      #
# implemented queue and the 'queue' ADT (abstract data type)#
###############################################################
from pythonds import Queue
import time


class MyQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0, item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)


q = Queue()


# Steps:
# 1) Enter 10 to five items in both 'MyQueue' and 'Queue'
# 2) This should be done from instance of the various classes
# 3) Check the number of steps that it takes to remove items from
#    these object instances.

m = MyQueue()
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1, 100001):
    m.enqueue(i)
t2 = time.time()

exec_time = t2 - t1

# m.dequeue()

t3 = time.time()
for u in range(1, 100001):
    q.enqueue(u)
t4 = time.time()

exec_time2 = t4 - t3


t5 = time.time()
if not q.isEmpty():
    while q.items:
        q.dequeue()
t6 = time.time()
exec_time3 = t6 - t5

t7 = time.time()
if not m.items:
    while m.items:
        m.dequeue()
t8 = time.time()
exec_time4 = t8 - t7

print("")
print("----------------------")
print("Enqueue Operations")
print("----------------------")
print("MyQueue Result 1: ",     exec_time)
print("Python Queue Result 2: ", exec_time2)
print("----------------------")
print("Dequeue Operations")
print("----------------------")
print("MyQueue Result 1: ",      exec_time3)
print("Python Queue Result 2: ", exec_time4)
```

Results:

```
----------------------
Enqueue Operations
----------------------
MyQueue Result 1:  3.1316871643066406
Python Queue Result 2:  3.1880860328674316
----------------------
Dequeue Operations
----------------------
MyQueue Result 1:  0.028588533401489258
Python Queue Result 2:  9.5367431640625e-07
```

Comment: It depends on **what** you want to measure? Time complexity? Real CPU usage? Memory usage? Behaviour under concurrency? Ease of using? Length of structure's name?

Comment: @freakish time complexity will do.

Comment: I have proposed time.time()  but timeit module is more addapted. It will do multiple run and give statistical result

Comment: @Julien will improve the analysis with `timeit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python time.time() to measure execution time for each queue.
the test should be run multiple times with at least 1000 elements in the structure to have a "decent" execution time.

```
import time

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1, 50000):
  m.enqueue(i)
t2 = time.time()
exec_time = t2-t1
```

Do this with m and q and enqueue/dequeue you can compare execution times

Comment: What of doing: `while not m.isEmpty: m.dequeue()` then time it?

Comment: @udoyen you can time like you want. Note that the loop will have an execution time too (and can be estimated). Some end condition may be more efficient than other.
Do not hesitate to edit your post to give us measurement results.

Comment: finished the design. If I may ask its ok to edit post and add update design and results, no penalties if I do that?

Comment: @udoyen I'm new here but I think this is OK (no penality for sure), add an EDIT title and add your design/results

Comment: just added the time results.